# Plot multiple contourf and save into jpegs

Tags: image, matlab

I need to use the following several times. How can I save multiple jpegs?

Here "B" is an 'm by n' matrix. I have multiple such matrices.

figure

```
contourf(B,zlevs,'LineStyle','none');
colormap jet
colorbar 

  hold all
  plot(512,512,'k.')

  print('file_name_001','-djpeg')
```

Comment: Take your time to consider the difference between `print` and `saveas`, to find out which one is most suitable for your needs. [Here's](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11862-difference-between-saveas-and-print-commands) some corresponding discussion, and a lot of folks say that [export-fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) at the File Exchange is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i = 1:n
f = figure;
contourf(B,zlevs,'LineStyle','none');
colormap jet
colorbar 
hold all
plot(512,512,'k.')
print(['file_name_00',num2str(i),'.jpg','-djpeg')
close(f)
end
```

Comment: I suggest changing call to `B=multiB(:,:,i); contourf(B,...`, in which case the sample code will not export the same image `n` times. AND, call `hold off` after the print to avoid cluttering the same figure window.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @AndrasDeak. I forgot about hold. I don't know anything of the data structure of `B` so I did not bother to iterate through it. But indeed, this will save the same figure n times. I'm sure the person who asked the question can figure that out!

Comment: @KarnaDesai I'm glad we could help. If my post answered your question, please accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark.